# Numpy: Prevent Float16 arrays from being transformed to Float32

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on some computation that is consuming a lot of memory. I notice that one of my functions, reproduced below, runs my computer out of memory and says that it is trying to make it float64. I cannot reproduce the function below outputting float 64 here, but the calculation here takes float16 arrays and outputs float32, so its somewhat problematic.

How can I make Python stick to float16 (or is there lower without going int?)

```
import numpy as np
xd1 = np.random.uniform(-1, 0, 10).astype(np.float16).reshape(5, 2)
xd2 = np.random.uniform(-2, 0, 10).astype(np.float16).reshape(5, 2)
def test_me(data1, data2):
    data1 = np.deg2rad(data1).astype(np.float16)
    data2 = np.deg2rad(data2).astype(np.float16)

    lat1 = data1[:, 0]
    lng1 = data1[:, 1]

    lat2 = data2[:, 0]
    lng2 = data2[:, 1]

    diff_lat = lat1[:, None] - lat2
    diff_lng = lng1[:, None] - lng2
    d = np.sin(diff_lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1[:,None])*np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(diff_lng/2)**2
    return 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(d)).astype(np.float16)
test_me(xd1, xd2)
```

Comment: replace `2 * 6371` with `np.array(2 * 6371, dtype=np.float16)`

Comment: Bear in mind that modern processors can't actually do arithmetic on float16 values.  They'll all have to be converted to floats or doubles to do any work.  Those conversions cost time, and of course you lose precision each time.  You only get 10 bits of precision in a float16.

Comment: For speed, then, should all the computations be done at float64/32 and then only at the end transformed to float16?